# No Provider for AngularFire - using Core Module / App Module

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, singleton

I have a `core module` within my a`Angular 2` application, inside this module I'm trying to create a singleton instance of my `firebase configuration`.

My Core Module:

```
import { NgModule, ModuleWithProviders, Optional, SkipSelf } from '@angular/core';
import { FirebaseConfigService } from './service/firebase-config.service';


@NgModule({
 imports: [],
 exports: [],
 declarations: []
})

export class CoreModule {

// Checks to see if an instance of core module already exists, if so throw and error
constructor( @Optional() @SkipSelf() parentMoedule: CoreModule) {

    if (parentMoedule){
        throw new Error("Core Module already exists. Only import in the root / app module");
    }

}

// this will only be called from app.module, if core module hasn't already 
// been created somewhere else within the application.
static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
        ngModule: CoreModule,
        providers: [ FirebaseConfigService ]
    };
}

}
```

As you can see within the `forRoot` function I reference FirebaseConfigService inside the providers, FirebaseConfigService looks like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

// https://github.com/angular/angularfire2
import { AngularFireModule } from 'angularfire2';

// Constants
import { FIREBASE_CONFIG } from '../constant/constants';



@Injectable()
export class FirebaseConfigService {
   constructor() {
       this.configureApp();
   }

   configureApp() {
      AngularFireModule.initializeApp(FIREBASE_CONFIG);

   }
}
```

inside `configureApp` I initialize my firebase connection by referring to FIREBASE_CONFIG which consists of this:

```
export const FIREBASE_CONFIG = {
apiKey: "apiKey",
authDomain: "projectId.firebaseapp.com",
databaseURL: "https://databaseName.firebaseio.com",
storageBucket: "bucket.appspot.com"
```

};

This `Core Module` is then imported into `App.Module` the issue I have is when I try to do:

```
 constructor(af: AngularFire) {

 }
```

Within my `app.component.ts` I get the following error: No Provider for `AngularFire`

Can someone please share some knowledge on how I go about getting the `FirebaseConfigService` to work within `CoreModule`?

Comment: I'm not sure any of this is needed. Why so much deviation from the [setup guide](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2#example-use)? Why not just `import {AngularFire} from 'angularfire2';` and then `  constructor(af: AngularFire) { }`?

Comment: @Kato I'm using a core module which is a singleton module, that way I initialize Firebase within this module and its shared as one instance through out the application.

Comment: To what end? If the goal is to get a single collection of data, then `this.singletondata = af.database.list(...)` will do just fine in your core module, to obtain a list you can share throughout the app. If you're trying to turn the AngularFire lib itself into a singleton, you're wasting time optimizing the library, which should take care of anything important here on its own.